# How do I backup everything?

Tags: partition, livecd, rescue

What can I use to create a backup image of my entire system that will be saved on a LAN computer via SSH? If I break anything later, I want to be able to restore my entire system as it was before the backup in minutes. Is there a Live CD that can "save backup image to ssh://..." and "restore from backup image ssh://..."?

Comment: Sounds like you should do your experiments in a Virtual Machine (Eg. using VirtualBox). This provides snapshots that you can revert to. For an entire backup of your system you can investigate on creating a `dd` image of your /dev/sda. This will include the bootsector and will therefore recover the whole system. It is a lengthy process though. You should specify more details about what you are trying to do and why you think you need it.

Comment: Clonezilla does work from a live cd, and can backup/restore disk/partition images to a variety of locations, ranging from local (such as another disk) to remote (another machine) including via ssh.

Comment: `dd` is far from ideal, particularly if you dd an entire drive; it's tricky to get single files out of it (which is a much more common restore scenario in practice than starting over from a clean slate), it's slow, plain dd uses excessive amounts of disk space due to its bit-by-bit copying, and for it to work well on restore, you need a drive of the exact same size as the original. **Better** to copy the files and `dd` the boot sector and boot loader part of the MBR if you can't be bothered to type `grub-install '(sd0)'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) would be a suitable product for a whole-disk image. It works in a fashion similar to Ghost.

Answer (score 2):

[Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/#benefits) is a possible solution.

But If you want to, you can also use the command-line:

On the receiver side:
`netcat ...>yourdisk.dat.gz`

On the sender side:
`dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M|gzip -|netcat ...`